In go_route, and flutter web, how to handle back and forward button in the browser
My project is using statefulShellRoute.indexdStack, and using bloc to manage state for the sidebar (using for turn true on the current sellected menuItem of sidebar). When I tap or press f5(refresh button) the route worked perfectly but when I press back/ forword button in browser, just the content view was changed. The sidebar menu not update index. So how can I fix it?
*Noted: *I use navigationShell.goBranch for redirection. *I call bloc update index function in every StatefulShellBranch-GoRoute builder. And I debugged when tap back/forward button, this builder not recall.
Expected:
I press back/ forword button in browser, both the content view and sidebar will be changed/updated.
Thank you for your help.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
